# past simple or past continuous

Tags: past-tense

A: Which hotel were you in when you lost your
passport?
B: I don’t remember. I visited many places during my
European tour and I ____________ (stay) in many different hotels.

do i have to use Past simple or past continuous  with the verb "stay" ?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't 'visited' set the pattern? Though if you're still on the tour, you should use 'I don’t remember. I have visited many places during my European tour and I have stayed in many different hotels.' Probably using 'I've' rather than 'I have'.

Comment: I'm asking about "stay" in the last sentence .

Comment: 'Visited' sets the pattern in your given sentence. The tour is over. You stayed (past simple) in many hotels.